# Create users using bash script

Tags: shell-script

> INTERACTIVE SCRIPT
>
> The script should ask for the number of accounts the user wants to create and the prefix of the name. then it should create the number of accounts the user specify but should skip any user that is already created
>
> ie user03 exists, if it does then skip to the next available number, ie user04 or user05.*******

This is the script I already wrote but won't work the way it should:

```
#!/bin/bash
Clear
Declare -I num
Start=1
Echo -n “Enter number of accounts to be created: “
Read num
Echo -n “Enter user prefix: (student or user)”
Read pre
Echo “”
For I in { $num }
Do
    Echo “Adding user”
    Useradd -m $pre$num
    ((num++))
done
```

Comment: We are happy to help you if you have trouble with _specific_ parts of your homework. However, simply dumping your assignment here, without even bothering to format it as a question and instead leaving it as a set of commands telling us what to do is not welcome. Try to write the script yourself and then, if you have trouble with specific parts of it, come and ask us about those. But ask a question, don't just copy the assignment verbatim!

Comment: @DavidLloyd Thank you. Your question was edited to properly format the code as such. The "ask a question" box (and the [help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)) has some guidance on how to do that, and more. Also, you may find it useful to familiarize with automated tools such as [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/), which will point out basic issues in your code, if any.

Comment: Thank you, that's much better! Are you writing this script using a word processor? I see you have `“` and `”` and have capitalized the first letter of every line. This will never run, you will have syntax errors all over the place. is that what you mean by "it won't work"?

Comment: No, i only copy it in word to be able to post it. It won't copy directly from nano editor here. I am doing it is Centos-7

Comment: @DavidLloyd We _need_ to see the code that you are actually running! Or else we'll spend useless time pointing out issues that don't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have written your script in a word processor that have capitalized words that shouldn't be capitalized (command names ar case sensitive on Unix), and used fancy typographical double quotes (`“...”` instead of `"..."`).  Do consider writing your scripts in a simpler text editor such as `nano`, `emacs` or `vim`. The site https://www.shellcheck.net/ is very helpful for spotting simpler errors in scripts.

Take that as a hint that all command names should be lower-case and that you need to change the quotes.

Your loop is also a bit strange. On one hand you seem to want to loop over `{ $num }` (which I don't know what it means), and on the other you increment `num` inside the loop.  Note that `num` is the number inputted by the user, so incrementing it makes no sense.  Let's assume that you update the variable in the loop:

```sh
number=1
while [ "$num" -ne 0 ]; do
   # code here that increments "number",
   # and conditionally decrements "num"
done
```

Remember that you have to keep track of the number used in the username *as well as* the number of created users.  You need to do this to know both when you have created the correct number of users, and to be able to skip usernames that are already existing on the system. Here I'm choosing to *decrement* `num` until it reaches zero, while keeping the number used in usernames in the variable called `number`.

Inside the loop, you will have to *try* to create user `$pre$number`, and if that succeeds, you decrement `num`. In each iteration, you then always increment `number`.  You iterate until `num` reaches zero, which means that you have created all the users.

Assuming that `adduser` returns a sane exit status for succeeding and failing (note: I'm not a Linux user, so I don't know what happens on CentOS if you try to create an already existing user), you could add a user using

```
if adduser -m "$pre$number"; then
    # adduser succeeded, we've created a new user, decrement num
    num=$(( num - 1 ))
fi
number=$(( number + 1 ))
```

Or, you could *check whether the proposed username exists* first using `getent`:

```
if ! getent passwd "$pre$number" >/dev/null; then
    # the user don't exist, create it
    adduser -m "$pre$number"
    num=$(( num - 1 ))
fi
number=$(( number + 1 ))
```

The `getent passwd` command will fail if the given username does not exist on the system.  We use this fact here to avoid calling `adduser` with an existing username.

I'll ignore most of the code in the beginning of your script, but I'll just point out that declaring `num` as integer is not needed, and that `read -p 'prompt' var` reads a value from the user with a specific prompt, so the `echo` statements are not needed.

You may also want to consider the fact that the `$pre` string in your code actually is accepted even though it may not be the string `student` or `user` (as the output from you current code suggests that it should be).

You should also account for the case where `$pre` may be invalid in a username, for example, when it contains a space.  Depending on how you write the code, and if you don't check that `$pre$number` is as a username, this may mean failing to create any accounts, or trying to create an infinite number of accounts.